# redirect powershell script output to a file using UFT16 encoding

Tags: powershell, unicode, utf-16

I need to run a powershell command from C++ application. This powershell command need to redirect powershell script output to a file using UFT16 encoding.

I run the following command, but out.txt is not in UFT16, but seems in UTF8.

```
powershell.exe -File  myps.ps1 > out.txt
```

I also tried the following. But the error is "'out-file' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file."

```
powershell.exe -File myps.ps1 | out-file "enctest.txt" -encoding unicode
```

Maybe should use `-Command`? How to do this?

Comment: Maybe you should include the relevant code so we have a better chance of pointing out the problem.

Comment: Write-Host “Hello, World!” is the content of my powershell script

Answer (score 1):

As you already know, `Out-File` is a PowerShell cmdlet, so it won't make sense in the context of a process argument (if you're trying to launch `powershell.exe` as a new process directly), nor will it make sense to `cmd.exe` (default shell when you invoke a `system()` call).

> Maybe should use "-Command"? How to do this?

Absolutely!

Something like this should do:

```
powershell.exe -Command "& C:\path\to\my.ps1 | Out-File enctest.txt -Encoding unicode"
```

The `>` operator would also work with `-Command`, as output redirection encoding defaults to UTF16LE (*inside* PowerShell at least):

```
powershell.exe -Command "& C:\path\to\my.ps1 > enctest.txt"
```

Comment: powershell.exe -Command "& C:\path\to\my.ps1 | Out-File enctest.txt -Encoding unicode" didn't redirect the output of the script to enctest.txt, it output to the console instead. C:\temp>powershell.exe -Command "& C:\temp\myps.ps1 | Out-File enctest.txt -Encoding unicode"
Hello, World!

Comment: Does `myps.ps1` contain something like `Write-Host "Hello World!"`? `Write-Host` writes directly to the host application (ie. the console screen buffer), not to `stdout`. It won't work. Use `Write-Output` (`echo`) instead of `Write-Host`

Comment: I tried "Write-Output" and it works. Thanks! But the problem is that in reality, I don't have control of the script. I only write code to redirect the output of the script to file. What if myps.ps1 contains Write-Host instead of Write-Output, is there anyway to do the same thing?  "powershell.exe -File  myps.ps1 > out.txt" works for Write-Host except it doesn't do unicode.